# Difference between View Data,View Bag and Temp Data in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the difference between View Data,View Bag and Temp Data in MVC ? What are the situations where one can be more useful? What would be a code snippet where one can be used and another can't?

Comment: Read the documentation. [ViewBag,ViewData,TempData](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-mvc/1286/viewbag-viewdata-tempdata#t=201608021547238510726)

Comment: http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3-applications/